# Save a class created with the Builder pattern in Room

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I need to create a table in my db where I can save Filters so I created this class like this:

```
@Entity
class Filter private constructor(
    val name: String?,
    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
    val sortBy: Sort?,
    val withGenres: List<Int>?,
    val withCast: List<Int>?,
) : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null

    data class Builder(
        var name: String? = null,
        var sortBy: Sort? = null,
        var withGenres: List<Int> = listOf(),
        var withCast: List<Int> = listOf(),
    ) {
        fun name(name: String) = apply { this.name = name }
        fun sortBy(sort: Sort?) = apply { this.sortBy = sort }
        fun withGenres(genresId: List<Int>) = apply { this.withGenres = genresId }
        fun withCast(castIds: List<Int>) = apply { this.withCast = castIds }
        fun build() = Filter(name, sortBy, withGenres, withCast)

    }

    /**
     * Sorting options, default order is Descendant (desc)
     */
    enum class Sort {
        POPULARITY, RELEASE_DATE, REVENUE, VOTE_AVERAGE;

        private var order: Order = Order.DESC

        override fun toString(): String {
            return this.name.lowercase() + "." + this.order.name.lowercase()
        }

        fun setOrder(order: Order) {
            this.order = order
        }

        enum class Order {
            ASC, DESC
        }

    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "sortBy: ${sortBy.toString()}, withGenres: $withGenres"
    }
}
```

But upon compilation I get the following errors:

- Cannot configure how to save field withGenres into database
- Cannot configure how to save field withCast into database
- Entities and POJOs must have public constructor
- Cannot find setter for field (all the fields)

How can I modify the code so that it works, what are the problems?

Comment: All of the errors tell you what to do. The only thing that is not absolutely clear might be those first two - `Room` doesn't know how to save a list of integers.

Comment: Room entities can only be primitives, Strings, enums, or if annotated with `@Embedded`, another data class where all its properties are primtives, Strings, or enums. Otherwise, you need to provide [TypeConverters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data).
You can't have a private constructor. The Builder pattern is unnecessary in Kotlin anyway because you can provide default values for constructor parameters directly in the definition of the data class.

Comment: You don't need to provide type converters for an enum, but you do need them for a `List<Int>`. The error about finding setters for fields will go away when you make your constructor public, because then it won't need setters.